# Import Grapevine (5.0.0-rc.7) into Unity project/NuGet Package not shown in NuGetForUnity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nuget, grapevine

I am trying to import [Grapevine (Version 5.0.0, release candidate 7)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grapevine/5.0.0-rc.7) into my Unity Project (Unity Version 2021.1). Therefore, I use [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity). If I type in "Grapevine", the search results show me "Grapevine" (Version 4.2.2) and "Grapevine.Core" (Version 4.1.1.2), however the newest pre-release of Grapevine is not shown. I played around and also activated "Show All Versions" and "Show Prereleases". Unfortunately, this was not successful.

[image]

As an alternative, I tried to import the NuGet package manually by placing the DLL file (.Net Standard 2.0) into the Assets/Plugins folder. I tried to install all dependencies, however, there are still lots of errors.

[image]
[image]

My questions are:

1. Can someone help out and describe how it might be possible to install the newest version of Grapevine via NuGetForUnity (or another package manager)? This would avoid that I have to install all dependencies manually.
2. In case I have to do it manually, can someone help out regarding the error messages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to "work around" the GUI of the NuGetForUnity package manager.

You can install the 4.2.2 version of the desired package and then change the version in `Assets/packages.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Grapevine" version="5.0.0-rc.7" />
</packages>
```

Probably you can also add the above line directly in the config without installing the old version before.

After you changed this, you might need to refresh the packages in the NuGetForUnity GUI and/or restart Unity.

After the above steps I could use the package and compile the project successfully.

It might still be worth to add a bug report to [NuGetForUnity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity).